# Sencha touch 2 JSONP store error

Tags: extjs

I got an error and tried to trace the problem. When I replaced JSONP values into inline values, it works well. It seemed the program couldn't make html with the template code. However I couldn't fix it so far. Does anyone have a solution?

Full error trace is below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertFirst' of null
Ext.define.doAddHeadersencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:62207
Ext.define.findGroupHeaderIndicessencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:62199
Ext.define.doRefreshHeaderssencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:61928
Ext.define.doFiresencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:18703
Ext.define.firesencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:18629
Ext.define.doDispatchEventsencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:25873
Ext.define.dispatchEventsencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:25844
Ext.define.doFireEventsencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:28915
Ext.define.fireEventsencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:28885
Ext.define.loadRecordssencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:38573
Ext.define.onProxyLoadsencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:38239
Ext.define.processResponsesencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:31530
(anonymous function)sencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:31960
Ext.apply.callbacksencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:8877
Ext.define.handleResponsesencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:13916
(anonymous function)sencha-touch-all-debug-w-comments.js:3105
```

My source code and the JSONP values are below:

```
Ext.define("Word", {
    extend : "Ext.data.Model",
    fields : [ 'id', 'word' ]
});

var xstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'Word',
    sorters : 'word',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('id')[0];
    },
    proxy : {
        type : 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://xxx.com/api/index.php/word/all',
        extraParams : {
            sid : user_storage.user.session_key
        },
        callbackKey : 'callback',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data'
        }
    },
    autoLoad : true
});

var groupingBase = {
    itemTpl : '<div class="contact2"><strong>{word}</strong>{id}</div>',
    mode : 'SINGLE',
    allowDeselect : true,
    disclosure : true,
    grouped : true,
    indexBar : true,
    onItemDisclosure : {
        scope : 'test',
        handler : function(record, btn, index) {
            alert('Disclose more info for ' + record.get('id'));
        }
    },
    store : xstore
};

var list = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', Ext.apply(groupingBase));
list.fullscreen = true;
list.show();
```

.

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback1({"code":"200","data":[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","glossary_id":"1","word":"dictionary","created_at":"2011-11-14 00:00:00","user_name":"xxxxxx"},{"id":"2","user_id":"1","glossary_id":"1","word":"application","created_at":"2011-11-15 00:00:00","user_name":"xxxxxx"}]})
```

The replaced source code is below:

```
 var xstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'Word',
    sorters : 'word',
    getGroupString : function(record) {
        return record.get('id')[0];
    },
    data : [ {
        id : '1',
        word : 'Maintz'
    }, {
        id : '2',
        word : 'Spencer'
    }, {
        id : '3',
        word : 'Avins'
    } ]
});
```

Thank you.